# Is there a way to load an activity into a certain part of the screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, loading

On my app, I have a menu that I want to display for every activity and different page I have. The problem is that I can't find a way to apply this menu to ALL activities, nor can I find a way to load an activity into a certain part of the screen.

There is a generous sized rectangle in the center of the screen and I would love to have it so that whenever I open a new screen that screens layout loads inside the rectangle.

Or am I just going to have to copy and paste the xml code for every layout?

Comment: you could have a MyActivity extends Activity that takes care of the menu and SomeActivities extends MyActivity for all your activity sharing that menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). You can define a `Fragment` that can be reused in every `Activity` in your application without having to duplicate its logic between different `Activities`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that the menu is always there, but when someone clicks on a button it keeps the current menu, but loads the different screen as a fragment into the activity. That way I don't have to load the menu into the new screen everytime, and the overall load time is cut down.

Answer (score 1):

You cant load `Activity` to a certain part of screen. For that (as suggested by @Egor) use `Fragment`.

However, regarding the common menu thinggy, I suggest you to create a base class which `extends Activity` and contains all the stuff you want to be commonly available in your activities. Later, use your base class to extend your activities.

Comment: I would do that, but I feel like it would be hard to load my specific screen into that designated section.

Answer (score 0):

There are someways to do this.
One is to write a Custom Menu that you can inflate by `onCreateOptionsMenu`, alternatively with the ActionBar. 
Also you can do this by writing a separate xml with your menu and add it to all your layout-xmls with the `<include>` Tag. 
The third way is using the Fragments-Class: [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should never be cutting and pasting xml code from one layout to the next.. that is why we have includes:

```
<include layout="@layout/header"/>
```

don't over think your problem, you should look into fragments so that you can create reusable widgets like a menu, or extend your activity to abstract away your menu logic.